# Delphi UDP Hole Punching: on internet not always works

Tags: delphi, udp, firemonkey, indy10, hole-punching

I'm trying to implement UDP Hole Punching with Delphi with Indy and Firemonkey technology.

I have tried to follow this document: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/1959162_Peer-to-Peer_Communication_Across_Network_Address_Translators

The program seems to work but is NOT stable.

If I work on a system on the local intranet no problem.
If I work on an internet, it doesn't always work and I don't know why.

I have created two applications.

The first is server side.
Everytime all clients connect correctly to server.
The server registers the Local IP and Internet IP pairs in a variable (fPeers).

I created an IdUDPServer instance.
This is the “Connect push button” code:

```
procedure TForm1.B_ConnectClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  vIdSocketHandle: TIdSocketHandle;
begin
  if IdUDPServer.Active then
  begin
    IdUDPServer.Active := False;
    B_Connect.Text := 'Connect';
  end
  else
  begin
    IdUDPServer.Bindings.Clear;
    vIdSocketHandle := IdUDPServer.Bindings.Add;
    vIdSocketHandle.IP := GStack.LocalAddress;
    vIdSocketHandle.Port := E_POrt.Text.ToInteger;

    IdUDPServer.Active := True;
    B_Connect.Text := 'Disconnect';
  end;
end;
```

During the IdUDPServerUDPRead event I capture the Local and Internet IP addresses of the clients that connect.
In the TStringLIST called fPeerIP I add the list of addresses.

```
procedure TForm1.IdUDPServerUDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
  const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var vPair: string;
    vData: string;
    vString: string;
    vLog: string;
begin
  vPair := ABinding.PeerIP + ':'+ABinding.PeerPort.ToString;
  vData := BytesToString(AData);
  vLog := '';

  if leftstr(vdata,7) = 'LOCALIP' then
  begin
    vString := vPair+#9+lsExtract(vData,2,',');

    if fPeerIP.IndexOfName(vString) = -1 then
    begin
      fPeerIP.Add(vString);
      M_Peers.Lines.Add(vString);

      vLog := vLog + vString + #13#10;
      IdUDPServer.Send(ABinding.PeerIP, ABinding.PeerPort, 'Peer aggiunto alla lista');
    end;

  end
  else vLog := vData;
end;
```

On the client side, I created an IdUDPServer instance which, upon connection, sends a string to the server.

```
procedure TForm2.B_ConnectClick(Sender: TObject);
var vIdSocketHandle: TIdSocketHandle;
    vLocalAddressList: TIdStackLocalAddressList;
    vI: Integer;
    vSendLIST: TStringLIST;
begin
  if IdUDPServer.Active then
  begin
    Timer.Enabled := False;
    IdUDPServer.Active := False;
    B_Connect.Text := 'Connect';

    M_Networks.Lines.Clear;
    M_Debug.Lines.Clear;
    LB_Peers.Items.Clear;
  end
  else
  begin
    try
      vSendLIST := TStringLIST.Create;
      IdUDPServer.Bindings.Clear;

      vLocalAddressList :=  TIdStackLocalAddressList.Create;
      GStack.GetLocalAddressList(vLocalAddressList);
      M_Networks.Lines.Clear;
      for vI := 0 to vLocalAddressList.Count-1 do
      begin
        if vLocalAddressList.Addresses[vI].IPVersion = id_IPV4 then
        begin
          M_Networks.Lines.Add(vLocalAddressList.Addresses[vI].IPAddress);
          vSendLIST.Add(Format('LOCALIP,%s:%d',[vLocalAddressList.Addresses[vI].IPAddress,E_ClientPort.Text.ToInteger]));
        end;
      end;

      vIdSocketHandle := IdUDPServer.Bindings.Add;
      vIdSocketHandle.Port :=  E_ClientPort.Text.ToInteger;
      vIdSocketHandle.IP := '0.0.0.0';


      IdUDPServer.Active := True;
      for vI := 0 to vSendLIST.Count-1 do
      IdUDPServer.Send(E_Server.Text, E_Port.Text.ToInteger, vSendLIST[vI]);

      B_Connect.Text := 'Disconnect';
      if Assigned(vSendLIST) then FreeAndNil(vSendLIST);
    finally
      if Assigned(vLocalAddressList) then FreeAndnil(vLocalAddressList);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Also on the client side, in the IdUDPServerUDPRead event I detect the list of Peers (function sent by the server) and send a "PING" to each connected peer.

I realize maybe I have given little information.
I'd like to know your opinion and possibly indicate to me if I made a mistake in the process that activates the Hole Punching.

Thanks in advance
LS

Comment: The solution is not so simple when clients are behind different NATs, or different layers of NAT.  Think you need to re-read sections 3.4 and 3.5 of the document you linked.

Comment: On a side note, in your `OnUDPRead` event, you should be using `ABinding.SendTo()` instead of `IdUDPServer.Send()`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is theoretically right and may work on some NAT routers but it will not work on the rest

I have been trying to achieve UDP Hole Punching for many years but it's really complicated,

you need to combine many NAT Traversal mechanisms together to make it work in the most cases

Reading about [STUN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN), [TURN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traversal_Using_Relays_around_NAT) and [ICE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Connectivity_Establishment) mechanisms may help

Comment: Thank you, I read a lot of documents but it’s not easy to implement a STUN Server/Client or ICE without spend a lot of time. It’s incredible: nobody had implemented these softwares in Delphi.....